# Using LSTM for regression always results in a suspiciously similar numbers in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm trying to create a LSTM network for natural language processing problem. As a toy example for learning, I'm trying to predict number of likes from a Facebook message content, hence a regression (predicting a number) as opposed to classification.

The input data consist of 24000 items, each looking like this:

```
[[361], [587], [26], [1], [3], [2], [1], [918], ..., [0], [0], [0]]
```

Each number corresponds to a distinct word, short messages are filled in with zeros. A quite standard approach in NLP I believe.

The target is 24000 numbers, each corresponding to number of likes for a respective message:

```
[3847, 1094, 633, 969, 4374, 1583, 350, 647, 22, 9, 886, 109, 629, 782, 831, ...]
```

I'm writing a LSTM network that's trying to fit this:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(MSG_LEN, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(50, MSG_LEN, 1), activation='tanh'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(int(MSG_LEN / 2), return_sequences=False, batch_input_shape=(50, MSG_LEN, 1), activation='tanh'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse')

model.fit(data['training_set']['data'], data['training_set']['target'],
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(data['test_set']['data'],
                           data['test_set']['target']),
          nb_epoch=10,
          batch_size=50)

predicted = model.predict(data['test_set']['data'],
                                batch_size=50)
```

Now predicted should contain an array of numbers, each predicting likes for respective test_set message.

Predicted looks like this:

```
[[ 0.99999225], [ 0.99999231], [ 0.99999225], [ 0.99999225], [ 0.99999225], [ 0.99999225], [ 0.99999225],  ...]
```

Now, I don't expect to get really useful results. Predicting Facebook likes is probably not a great idea to start with, but given that test target are integers from 0 to 100000, I'd expect the predicted data to be in similar range too.

Is there anything obviously wrong? Is this overfitting? Am I missing something elementary?